# Exibir imagem do FIREBASE em uma LISTVIEW

Tags: imagem, firebase, listview

Gostaria de saber como recuperar uma imagem no firebase e colocar em uma listview, vi aqui algumas perguntas iguais, segui as respostas que estão nelas mas nenhuma deu certo. Vi que um rapaz falou que usou uma recyclerView e deu certo, porém eu não consegui utiliza-la, alguém poderia me ajudar?
segue abaixo o código

ADAPTER

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_sessao_personalizada, parent, false);

        Sessoes sessao = sessoes.get(position);

        TextView nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista_sessao_personalizada_nome);
        TextView descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista_sessao_personalizada_descricao);
        final ImageView imagem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista_sessao_personalizada_imagem);

        nome.setText(sessao.getNomeSessao());
        descricao.setText(sessao.getDescricaoSessao());

        firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("configuracao").child("telaInicial").child("calendario");

        ValueEventListener post = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String imagemFire = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                Glide.with(act).load(imagemFire).into(imagem);
                Log.i("imagem", imagemFire);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        firebase.addValueEventListener(post);

       // Glide.with(act).load(imagemFire).into(imagem);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Activity que recebe o adapter

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logoImg = findViewById(R.id.logo_doeamor_id);

        firebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("configuracao").child("telaInicial").child("logo");

        ValueEventListener post = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String imagem = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imagem).into(logoImg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        firebase.addValueEventListener(post);

        sessoes = todasAsSessoes();
        listaDeSessoes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaDeSessoes);

        AdapterPersonalizado adapter = new AdapterPersonalizado(sessoes, MainActivity.this);

        listaDeSessoes.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

e a imagem sai assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Colega, com o link abaixo você irá entender como criar passo-a-passo, e de diversas maneiras, um RecycleView, que é o mesmo ListView, porém muito mais melhorado, otimizado e mais simples de implementar.

https://medium.com/android-dev-br/listas-com-recyclerview-d3f41e0d653c

Uma dica que eu te dou, é você utilizar a api Picaso, link abaixo, nela você baixa qualquer imagem do firebase sem nenhum problema e todas as imagens permanecem em cache, o que fará que seu app tenho um excelente desempenho.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Crie um array de alguma maneira com os links e alimente a seu RecycleView com ela. É o que eu faria.